# DateTime.AddSeconds won't show on label

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting a weird malfunction when using the DateTime.AddSeconds command in a loop. Label1 is supposed to show "NewDT" before the loop starts, but for some reason it doesn't. Funny thing is when add a Messagebox right over the loop, the label shows what I want it too.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Dt As DateTime = Now() 'It shows current datetime
    Dim NewDT As DateTime = Now()
    NewDT = NewDT.AddSeconds(10) 'It adds 10 seconds too the current datetime.
    Label1.Text = NewDT

    Do While NewDT.Second > DateTime.Now.Second 'Loops until system time matches NewDT

    Loop
    MsgBox("done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Code work properly for me without msgbox. try this `Label1.Text = NewDT.ToString`

Comment: a) your loop is comparing Seconds, not time; b) there is nothing inside your loop.  If you *were* changing the label, the loop would have to complete before the form updates.  Use `label1.Refresh` to force it to update.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks. Well I'm just using the loop to make the program wait until the time is matched. I know it's not ideal. Is there any better solution?

Comment: `NewDT` starts out Now+10 secs and would never execute if you were actually comparing time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no malfunction.

The `WM_PAINT` message is queued but only processed after you've "left" the function.

The reason as to why it works when you show a modal message box (`MsgBox`) is because the dialog calls [Application.DoEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents) which enables the application to process queued messages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the text of the label will not be updated untill the end of the sub.
After the `Label1.Text = NewDT` line, add `Label1.Refresh()`, and then NewDT will be presented before the loop starts.

If you want a more ideal solution, you can use the [Sleep method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly! Eminem helped me out, day cant get any better ;)